# Error loading patching payloadfailed to run commands: exit status 156

Tags: amazon-web-services, patch, aws-ssm

I'm automating my EC2 instances with Patch Manager and I'm getting this error.

`Error loading patching payloadfailed to run commands: exit status 156`

The error output logs are these:

```
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/apt-get
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
python3-apt is already the newest version (2.3.0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Using python binary: 'python3'
Using Python Version: Python 3.10.4
/usr/bin/curl
/usr/bin/wget
05/29/2022 01:11:51 root [INFO]: Downloading payload from https://s3.dualstack.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/aws-ssm-sa-east-1/patchbaselineoperations/linux/payloads/patch-baseline-operations-1.86.tar.gz
05/29/2022 01:11:52 root [INFO]: Attempting to import entrance file os_selector
05/29/2022 01:11:52 root [ERROR]: Error loading entrance module.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/common_startup_entrance.py", line 154, in execute
    entrance_module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/os_selector.py", line 11, in <module>
    import common_os_selector_methods
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/common_os_selector_methods.py", line 11, in <module>
    from patch_common.baseline_override import load_baseline_override
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/patch_common/baseline_override.py", line 6, in <module>
    from patch_common.downloader import download_file, load_json_file, is_access_denied
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/patch_common/downloader.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/session.py", line 29, in <module>
    import botocore.configloader
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/configloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import six
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/compat.py", line 25, in <module>
    from botocore.exceptions import MD5UnavailableError
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore.vendored import requests
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._collections import HTTPHeaderDict
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
05/29/2022 01:11:52 root [ERROR]: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/common_startup_entrance.py", line 154, in execute
    entrance_module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/os_selector.py", line 11, in <module>
    import common_os_selector_methods
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/common_os_selector_methods.py", line 11, in <module>
    from patch_common.baseline_override import load_baseline_override
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/patch_common/baseline_override.py", line 6, in <module>
    from patch_common.downloader import download_file, load_json_file, is_access_denied
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/patch_common/downloader.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/session.py", line 29, in <module>
    import botocore.configloader
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/configloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import six
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/compat.py", line 25, in <module>
    from botocore.exceptions import MD5UnavailableError
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore.vendored import requests
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._collections import HTTPHeaderDict
  File "/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Does anyone have an idea what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

What's the Ubuntu version being used here?

Looking at the Python version (Python 3.10.4) in the error logs, that target instance appears to be running Ubuntu 22.04, which is not yet supported by Patch Manager.

Below is the link for the supported operating systems in Patch Manager prerequisites documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/patch-manager-prerequisites.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).